# Collectionview FlowLayout scrolling disabling issue

Tags: ios, swift3, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have created custom class of FlowLayout for collectionview. Here is my class

```
class NodeLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
    var itemWidth : CGFloat
    var itemHeight : CGFloat
    var space : CGFloat

    var columns: Int{
        return self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    }
    var rows: Int{
        return self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
    }

    init(itemWidth: CGFloat, itemHeight: CGFloat, space: CGFloat) {
        self.itemWidth = itemWidth
        self.itemHeight = itemHeight
        self.space = space
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.itemWidth = 110
        self.itemHeight = 2090
        self.space = 1
        super.init()
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize{
        let w : CGFloat = CGFloat(columns) * (itemWidth + space)
        let h : CGFloat = CGFloat(rows) * (itemHeight + space)
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        let x : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.row) * (itemWidth + space)
        let y : CGFloat = CGFloat(indexPath.section) + CGFloat(indexPath.section) * (itemHeight + space)
        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let minRow : Int = (rect.origin.x > 0) ? Int(floor(rect.origin.x/(itemWidth + space))) : 0
        let maxRow : Int = min(columns - 1, Int(ceil(rect.size.width / (itemWidth + space)) + CGFloat(minRow)))
        var attributes : Array<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes> = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if columns == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        for i in 0 ..< rows {
            for j in minRow ... maxRow {
                attributes.append(self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: j, section: i))!)
            }
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Right Now collecitonview scroll is vertical and horizontal both, what I want to disable vertical scroll in collectionview. When I put         `self.scrollDirection = .horizontal` in class then also collectionview scroll is working in both ways.

Please help me with it.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: CollectionView is scrolling vertically because u have specified height as`let h : CGFloat = CGFloat(rows) * (itemHeight + space)` change it to match the height of collectionView and it wont scroll but that would also mean that some of your items would not be visible else reduce the height of each item such that their cumulative sum is equal to collectionView's height hope it helps

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I know that If I gave fixed height of collectionview frame then my content will be cut but I don't want like that.